# The Poor Farmer or A Poor Farmer? What fits best?

Tags: articles, definite-article

> [The] well salaried workaholic who is never home to strengthen the relationship with his wife and kids is likely to be less happier than [the] poor farmer in Thailand who spends half his day tending to his fields and the other half with his family.

The use of the definite article here doesn't refer to one specific person in both cases. Is that true that the reason to use the definite article here is to refer to this specific kind of person in general? Like this: `The lion is a great animal`
Not one specific well salaried workaholic and not one specific poor farmer but the whole class of these people in general, right? And using an indefinite article wouldn't change much.

Comment: Yes, you are right. Personally, I find this use old fashioned and rather patronising. I would prefer _a_ (or recast it in the plural). I note that _less happier_ appears to be a mistake.

Comment: I wondered about your use of 'patronising', then I remembered _All Things Bright and Beautiful:_ The rich man in his castle/The poor man at his gate/God made them high and lowly/And ordered their estate.

Comment: Note, it should be "less happy" or just "unhappier" not "less happier"--we don't pair more/less with adjectives that are already in comparative form.

Comment: Thank you, guys. Since it's from a book I'm surprised to know that the sentence contains the mistake with comparative form.

Comment: The book, which you **failed** to name, is "The Millionaire Fastlane: Crack the Code to Wealth and Live Rich for a Lifetime By MJ DeMarco", which is hardly a work of literature. I will not comment on the book, its philosophy, or the cult around its author, beyond saying that he got rich by selling books to people who want to dream about being rich. A well known pattern. Get rich by appealing to greed in the gullible.

Comment: @Michael Harvey I found a free version so the author isn't going to get richer. If there's one single sentence that might improve a person's life then the book is worth the price.

Comment: This is far from a *mistake*. It's purely subjective if the definite article is okay here or not. The discussion here is entirely one of style.